# MUI v5 passing props to CSS theme using styled()

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

Previously, in Material-UI v4, I had this bit of code

```
const { customPadding } = props;
const classes = useStyles({
    padding: customPadding,
} as any);
```

To pass props to the classes of an element.

But v5 uses `emotion` instead of JSS, where I do something like this instead.

```
const StyledContainer = styled(Container)(({theme}: any) => ({
    [`&.${classes.FullPageLayoutRoot}`]: (props: any) => ({
        minHeight: `calc(100vh - ${appBarHeight}px - ${theme.spacing(1)} - 1px)`,
        display: 'flex',
    }),

    [`&.${classes.middle}`]: {
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

    [`& .${classes.paper}`]: (props: any) => ({
        backgroundColor: grey[800],
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
        padding: theme.spacing(props.padding),
        minWidth: '100%',
    })
}));

...

return(
    <StyledContainer maxWidth={maxWidth} fixed className={clsx(classes.FullPageLayoutRoot, {
        [classes.middle]: middle,
    })}>
        <Paper className={clsx(classes.paper, classes.padding, className)} {...PaperProps} >
            {content}
        </Paper>
    </StyledContainer>
)
```

How would I accomplish this in Material-UI v5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're passed along with the `theme` property in the callback:

```
const MyDiv = styled("div", {
  // indicate that this prop name should be used to conditionally
  // style the component only and should not be spread to the DOM element.
  shouldForwardProp: (propName) => propName !== "isRed"
})(({ theme, isRed }) => ({
  backgroundColor: isRed ? "red" : theme.palette.primary.main
}));

export default function ThemeUsage() {
  return (
    <MyDiv isRed>Styled div with theme</MyDiv>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]